# HERE maps draggable & editable radius geoshapes (example : Circle)

Tags: javascript, here-api

i need help on modifying this code to make circle drag-gable and editable radius.

**example :** user should be able to drag circle to different location and change radius.

i am not sure if there is any param or option to pass value to activate this features, it will be really great help if any one can help me through.

Thanking you in advance.

```js
function addCircleToMap(map){
  map.addObject(new H.map.Circle(
    // The central point of the circle
    {lat:36.178699, lng:-115.146171},
    // The radius of the circle in meters
    1000,
    {
      style: {
        strokeColor: 'rgba(55, 85, 170, 0.6)', // Color of the perimeter
        lineWidth: 2,
        fillColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.7)'  // Color of the circle
      }
    }
  ));
}


//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: 'DemoAppId01082013GAL',
  app_code: 'AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg',
  useCIT: true,
  useHTTPS: true
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over las vegas
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.normal.map,{
  center: {lat:36.178699, lng:-115.146171},
  zoom: 13
});

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Now use the map as required...
addCircleToMap(map);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background: grey" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [HERE map API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/api-reference.html), you need to disable the default draggability of the underlying map when starting to drag a circle object:

```
map.addEventListener('dragstart', (ev) => {
    const target = ev.target;
    if (target instanceof H.map.Circle) {
        behavior.disable();
    }
}, false);
```

During circle dragging, you need to listen to the drag event and move the position of the circle:

```
map.addEventListener('drag', (ev) => {
    const target = ev.target,
        pointer = ev.currentPointer;
    if (target instanceof H.map.Circle) {
        target.setCenter(map.screenToGeo(pointer.viewportX, pointer.viewportY));
    }
}, false);
```

After finishing drag, you need to re-enable the default draggability of the underlying map.

```
map.addEventListener('dragend', (ev) => {
    const target = ev.target;
    if (target instanceof H.map.Circle) {
        behavior.enable();
    }
}, false);
```

You can change circle radius by calling `setRadius` on your circle object.

Comment: Thank you Matus Stastny, i merged your code with working snippet, can any one edit current code to make editable radius ? and is there any ways of making rectangle draggable? it will be great help thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addCircleToMap(map){
  var circle = new H.map.Circle(
    new H.geo.Point(36.1786991, -115.146171), //center
    1000, // Radius in meters
    {
      style: {
        strokeColor: '#FF0000', // Color of the perimeter
        lineWidth: 3,
        fillColor: 'rgba(226, 180, 183, 0.5)' // Color of the circle
      }
    }
  );
  circle.draggable = true;
  map.addObject(circle);
}


//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: 'DemoAppId01082013GAL',
  app_code: 'AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg',
  useCIT: true,
  useHTTPS: true
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over las vegas
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.normal.map,{
  center: {lat:36.178699, lng:-115.146171},
  zoom: 13
});

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
 
//Step 4, initilize drag for map objects.
    map.addEventListener('dragstart', (ev) => {
        const target = ev.target;
        if (target instanceof H.map.Circle) {
            behavior.disable();
        }
    }, false);

    map.addEventListener('drag', (ev) => {
        const target = ev.target,
            pointer = ev.currentPointer;
        if (target instanceof H.map.Circle) {
            target.setCenter(map.screenToGeo(pointer.viewportX, pointer.viewportY));
        }
    }, false);

    map.addEventListener('dragend', (ev) => {
        const target = ev.target;
        if (target instanceof H.map.Circle) {
            behavior.enable();
        }
    }, false);

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Now use the map as required...
addCircleToMap(map);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background: grey" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a little bit? The code looks great but what does it do?